# build failed after running a plugin in cordova

Tags: cordova, plugins, hockeyapp

I am working on hybrid mobile application using ionic + cordova.
i added this plugin in
https://github.com/instantiator/hockeyapp-phonegap

but after that i am getting this problem if i remove this then it will work

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:892: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:894: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:906: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:283: null returned: 2

Total time: 1 minute 51 seconds

F:\Repo\rtaProject\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s,/c,ant,debug,-f,F:\Repo\rtaProject\platforms\android\build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-gen
```

remember command given in githhub page is

```
phonegap plugin add https://github.com/instantiator/hockeyapp-phonegap.git
```

and i were run this

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/instantiator/hockeyapp-phonegap.git
```

Comment: did you run `cordova build` after adding the plugin? Is that the command that is failing?

Comment: yes this command showing above error

Comment: Try build using eclipse